# Property 'target' does not exist on type error using {...props}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm making a custom link component and passing `target="_blank"` and `rel="noreferrer"` as props and using `{...props}` assigned to the `<a>`.

```tsx
const ExternalLinkTwo: React.FC<{
  href: string;
  children: ReactNode;
}> = ({ href, children, ...props }) => (
  <a href={href} {...props}>
    {children}
  </a>
);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ExternalLinkTwo
        href="http://www.google.com"
        target="_blank" //throwing error here, why?
        rel="noreferrer"
      >
        Google 2
      </ExternalLinkTwo>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Getting this error on the `target` prop

> (JSX attribute) target: string
> Type '{ children: string; href: string; target: string; rel: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { href: string; children: ReactNode; } & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
> Property 'target' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { href: string; children: ReactNode; } & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)

[image: Edit React Typescript (forked)]

Comment: FYI, you don't need to define `children` in your props, you get the automatically from `React.FC`

Comment: What error is being thrown? You should include the full text of the error in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to support the normal set of `<a>` attributes but make `href` required, use something like this...

```ts
import { AnchorHTMLAttributes } from "react";

interface LinkProps extends AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> {
  href: string; // make href non-optional
}

const ExternalLinkTwo: React.FC<LinkProps> = ({ href, children, ...props }) => (
  <a href={href} {...props}>
    {children}
  </a>
);
```

You don't need to include `children` in your prop type. It's provided automatically via `React.FC`.

[image: Edit React Typescript (forked)]

---

An alternative is to simply extend `Record<string, string>` to accept any extra attributes.

```ts
interface LinkProps extends Record<string, string> {
  href: string;
}
```

Comment: @JenniferAlexis no worries. Hope you didn't mind me cleaning up your question a little. Should help others with the same problem find it